# How to tag a view?

Tags: views

Views in drupal allow to filter content. A single webpage can have many views. A way to get them sorted is to use a initial letter (as A_view_name).
Another one is to use tags.

I don't understand if tagging views is out of the box (with drupal 7 or 8), or I have to install some module (as https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag).

Comment: Why don’t you simply try if you can tag a view without the metatag module?

Comment: What do metatags have to do with filtering Views? This needs clarification.

Answer (score 5):

Click on the <kbd>edit view name/description</kbd> button

[image]

The following pops up, by default, you will see `default` is set as the view tag, I changed it to `example`

[image]

Now when you to to `/admin/structure/views`

[image]

You can click on the blue TAG header to sort by tag.

[image]

---

**PS:** The [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module is for SEO purposes.

> **Meta tags** are snippets of text that describe a page's content; the
>   meta tags don't appear on the page itself, but only in the page's
>   code. We all know tags from blog culture, and meta tags are more or
>   less the same thing, little content descriptors that help tell search
>   engines what a web page is about.
>
> [image]
>
> source: http://www.wordstream.com/meta-tags

Comment: Thank you. You wouldn't believe how long it took me to figure out how to tag a view for the view field formatter.